# Хочу сделать отступы в TextView

Tags: android, java

Как сделать отступы в TextView?

У меня слева кнопка, а справа должен быть текст, получается я высчитываю размер кнопки и делаю отступ.

Но беда  в том что я не знаю метода в TextView который бы говорил что, от 1 до 5 строки будет отступ, а дальше по стандарту без отступов.

Как такое сделать я в программировании не профи так что сильно не ругайтесь если что - то не так написал...

Comment: кнопку вставить внутрь TextView, что бы она обтекалась текстом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Покажи свой XML файл

если я тебя правильно понял
попробуй к TextView указать один из атрибутов:
android:paddinLeft = "10dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"

Как ты можешь догадаться можно ещё указать

paddinRight
paddingTop
и т.д.

Если тебе нужно это, то можешь посмотреть подробней про атрибуты здесь:
http://devpad.ru/post/item/4/android-vse-o-linearlayout-3.html

Я надеюсь ответил на твой вопрос)